# Toolbar elements cutting due to 150% DPI - MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc, dpi

The MFC application looks weird with 150% DPI settings on Windows 7.

When display settings on Windows 7 are changed to 150% following things happen:

1. Toolbar gets expanded a lot making menu items almost invisible.
2. In addition, a black gap get's introduced between the toolbar and application frame (as shown in new)
3. The app used to work fine a while ago (as shown in old). Many changes have been introduced to the app including integration of DevExpress.
   But nothing particularly changed in DPI settings.

Need help in understanding why this change might have occurred. And how to get rid of this unwanted zoom effect / DPI effect.

[image: Old and New look]

Comment: Found one more interesting thing. The problem does not occur on MAC VM. Both versions (old and new) run fine with 150% scale.

Comment: Actually it turns out, my colleague's machine shows it fine. Regardless of VM.
Most of my colleagues have the problem, but for few of them, it looks good.